# Protractor Angular 9: browser.executeAsyncScript() - window.ng is undefined

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular9, angular-e2e

I'm trying to reference one of my services while executing e2e tests. I need this to have possibility to enable/disable my feature toggles mocking mechanism, and could perform tests for both states on/off of some feature.

I've tried with:

```js
const data = await browser.executeScript(function() {
  //@ts-ignore
  return window.ng.getInjector(window.getAllAngularRootElements()[0]).get('MyService')
})
```

but the problem is that `window.ng` is undefined, I got error message:

```
Failed: javascript error: Cannot read property 'getInjector' of undefined
(Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122)
(Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}),platform=Linux 4.19.121-linuxkit x86_64)
```

I receive the same error when using `browser.executeAsyncScript()`

Tests are running in docker

Comment: sounds like you just don't have `window.ng` object in the page where you're trying to execute it

Comment: @sergey yes I don't have, but as far as i know i should have. Since Angular 9 window.ng is object for console debugging and testing. When I created a brand new project and execute this code, everything is fine, so I believe the problem lies somewhere in configuration of current project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The issue was inside my own configuration.

Tests were executed against different environment than I was expecting. This was environment in **production mode** and this is the reason that ng object was not available.